# Controlling flask server from commandline/GUI

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

at first: I am trying to write GUI for controlling Flask simple server, so I can distribute my app to noobs (using PyInstaller)

I am using multiprocessing to launch Flask and then turn it off, but turning it off seems to be the problem. I wrote simple cli-controller as a proof-of-concept but it ignores even sys.exit()

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
from myapp import app

def run():
    app.run()

server = Process(target=run)
server.start()
while True:
    x = raw_input("Input something:")
    if x == "x":
        server.terminate()
        server.join(timeout=10)
        print(server.exitcode)
        print("end here")
        break
print("All done!")
sys.exit(1)
```

But the result has blown my mind:
(<Enter> means I pressed enter)

```
user@localhost:~$ ./run.py 
Input something: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
Input something:x
None
end here
All done!
user@localhost:~$ <Enter> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 42, in <module>
    x = raw_input("Input something:")
EOFError
```

and Flask is still running...

1. I tried adding `server.join() after terminate() but Flask is running anyway`
2. I implemented the same without Flask (two infinite loops instead) and it works
3. I tried wrapping everything from `server=...` to `break` in `if __name__ == "__main__:"`with no result

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand, why previous versions doesn't work, but I found this solution:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import multiprocessing
from myapp import app

def make_ui(server):
    def terminate_server():
            if server is not None and server.is_alive():
                server.terminate()
            main.destroy()

    def toggle_server():
        global server
        if server.is_alive():
            server.terminate()
            server.join()
        else:
            if server.exitcode:
                server = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_in_behind, name="server")
            server.start()

    main = Tk()
    appname = Label(main, text="Sociometry v.0.0.1", anchor="center")
    appname.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=2)
    main.mainloop()



def run_in_behind():
    config = {
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1"
    }
    app.config.from_object(config)
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_in_behind, name="server")
    make_ui(server)
```